# Database showing what gridview should, gridview not completely filling

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

Just to clear things up so my title makes sense: I tested my query in my database and it did work, with all of the data showing. When I put it in the gridview it does not fill the last field. I'm not sure if it's because there are two datafields that are called 'notes', or maybe I'm just missing something and reading it over and over won't help.

Here is my query (I suck at formatting):

```
cmd.CommandText =
```

`@"SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.product_mgr, p.license_start_date, p.version, 
  pd.processor, pd.notes, ci.f_name, ci.l_name, ci.phone, ci.email, 
  ci.title, ci.notes FROM Customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @" p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @"Details pd ON p.customer_id = pd.customer_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactInfo ci ON c.customer_id = ci.customer_id ORDER BY customer_id";`

And here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvProd" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

    <Columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_id" headertext="Customer ID" />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_name" headertext="Customer Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_mgr" HeaderText="Product Mgr" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="license_start_date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="version" headertext="Product Version" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="processor" HeaderText="Payment Processor" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="Product Notes" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="f_name" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="l_name" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Position/Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="Contact Notes" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Shit I left the most important part out I think. The second notes field doesn't fill. I know there's data in it. But the other contact stuff fills so I know thats working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two fields named notes in the query. Add an alias to one of them and use it in the grid view.

```
cmd.CommandText =
@"SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.product_mgr, p.license_start_date, p.version, 
pd.processor, pd.notes AS product_notes, ci.f_name, ci.l_name, ci.phone, ci.email, 
ci.title, ci.notes AS contact_notes FROM Customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @" p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @"Details pd ON p.customer_id = pd.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactInfo ci ON c.customer_id = ci.customer_id ORDER BY customer_id";



<asp:GridView id="gvProd" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

    <Columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_id" headertext="Customer ID" />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_name" headertext="Customer Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_mgr" HeaderText="Product Mgr" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="license_start_date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="version" headertext="Product Version" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="processor" HeaderText="Payment Processor" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="product_notes" HeaderText="Product Notes" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="f_name" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="l_name" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Position/Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contact_notes" HeaderText="Contact Notes" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I didn't know this was a thing, thanks. I'll mark as answer when it's available

Comment: The names of the columns are how the software (be it SQL Server or .NET) distinguishes between columns. In this case chances are SQL Server gave the second notes column some generated name so it did not match. BTW was the first notes column displayed correctly?

Comment: If it wasn't before, it is now. The field was already empty to begin with (the database is still not fully populated), but I added some dummies in just to check.

Comment: Yeah, you may need an alias for that too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to give aliases to your Notes (in the query) and then use the aliases as the Datafield value for that column?

Maybe like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.product_mgr, p.license_start_date, p.version, 
pd.processor, pd.notes as Pd_Note, ci.f_name, ci.l_name, ci.phone, ci.email, 
ci.title, ci.notes as CI_Note FROM Customer c LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @" p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN " + p + @"Details pd ON p.customer_id = pd.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactInfo ci ON c.customer_id = ci.customer_id ORDER BY customer_id";
```

And then:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_id" headertext="Customer ID" />
    <asp:boundfield datafield="customer_name" headertext="Customer Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="product_mgr" HeaderText="Product Mgr" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="license_start_date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="version" headertext="Product Version" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="processor" HeaderText="Payment Processor" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Pd_Note" HeaderText="Product Notes" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="f_name" HeaderText="First Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="l_name" HeaderText="Last Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Position/Title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CI_Note" HeaderText="Contact Notes" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```